# Visual Studio 2022 convert spaces to tabs on checkout and back to spaces on checkin

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tabs

I'm working with people who want to make leading spaces mandatory in our DevOps codebase. I use tabs. Is there any way to configure Visual Studio 2022 to automatically convert leading spaces to tabs when I check out a file, and back to spaces when I check it in?

'''Edit:''' Oh and this project will use Git version control, so looks like the "Team Foundation check-in policy" trick won't work?

Comment: Why make life difficult for yourself? Just use the same system as the people you work with, as tabs or spaces do not affect the quality or efficiency of the code.

Comment: @OldBoy making life difficult for myself would be gritting my teeth and trying to work with thise spaces until the pain becomes unbearable.

Comment: And what about a shell script that converts tabs to spaces, and forth, in the desired files of your project directory?

Comment: _gritting my teeth and trying to work with thise spaces_. You mean rather than actually trying to make the code work?

Comment: @oldBoy I'm programming in C# not Python. The current code with tabs works just fine. It's not a matter of quality of code, it's a matter of quality of life.

Comment: @Éric this can work, if there's a way to automatically call the script from Visual Studio 2022 when checking the files in.